# How does C or ASM communicate with networking cards?

Tags: c, assembly, networking, kernel

I was wondering how does the C or ASM code from kernel communicate with network card. I can't find this anywhere. Like when I would write my own kernel , and wanted networking how would I go about that, would I need to have separate code for each networking card that exists?

Comment: You could start by reading the source code (for linux). Just to get an idea about how other people solved your problem.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Ethernet_devices.  One of the simplest widespread old NIC hardware interfaces is NE2000 (https://wiki.osdev.org/Ne2000), often provided by VMs as a virtual NIC in the guest machine.  Of course to actually do anything on the Internet, you need a whole network stack (IP, UDP, and TCP): https://wiki.osdev.org/Network_Stack.  It gives a good overview, including where the "driver for your NIC" comes in, along with scanning the PCI bus to discover NICs.

Comment: Yes, you need a device driver for each device that you use. There’s plenty of information about how to do this but you have to research each device separately; there’s no one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: For many types of devices, the driver creates descriptors in memory that tell the device what to do, and then signals the device using an MMIO write to initiate the operation. The device reads the descriptors, performs the operation, and either writes a status to memory or generates an interrupt.